# javascript and bootbox - lose of sincronicity

Tags: javascript, bootbox

I have been reading that javascript is single threaded and in some special cases can be asyncronous also. Somehow I have a piece of code that i dont understand why has this behaviour,seems to be contradictory with this idea of sincronicity.

I have a button, when it is clicked I want to open a confirmation dialog and if it is OK the answer I do the $.post() of the form after that. 
This is the function that I use inside the onclick event of the button:

```
            function bconfirm(text)
            {
                var res;

                bootbox.confirm(text, function(result) {

                 res = result;
                 alert("first");

                }); 

                alert("second");
                return res;

            }
```

Can someone tell me why always print "second" before "first"?
Shouldnt be logical that it is called before the **bootbox.confirm** and after that the rest of the main function?
Thanks.

Comment: Well, probably because `bootbox.confirm` is asynchronous.  and the second alert runs before your callback function gets called

Comment: is there a way to make bootbox.confirm syncronous in this situation?